# Two basic questions on congruence subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, arithmetic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$I have two questions related to congruence subgroups.

Let $$\Gamma=\Gamma_0(N)=\Big\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \subset \SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \mid c \equiv 0 \pmod{N} \Big\}$$ be a congruence subgroup.

1. I am wondering why $\Gamma \backslash \SL_2(\mathbb{R}) \simeq Z(\mathbb{R})\Gamma' \backslash \GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, where $$\Gamma'=\Big\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \subset \GL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \mid c \equiv 0 \pmod{N} \Big\}.$$ (Here, $Z(\mathbb{R})$ is the center of $\GL_2(\mathbb{R})$.) I think it might be true but I cannot prove it rigorously.
2. For $\alpha \in \GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$, consider the double coset decomposition
   $\Gamma \alpha \Gamma = \bigcup \Gamma a_i$ in $\GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$, where $a_i \in \GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$. Let $\mathbb{A}_f$ be the finite adele ring of $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $U_{\Gamma} \subset \GL_2(\mathbb{A}_{f})$ be an open compact subgroup such that $U_{\Gamma} \cap \GL_2(\mathbb{Q})=\Gamma$ and $\GL_2(\mathbb{A})=\GL_2(\mathbb{Q})GL_2(\mathbb{A}_f)$. I am wondering why the double coset decomposition $U_{\Gamma}\alpha U_{\Gamma}=\bigcup U_{\Gamma}a_i$ holds in $\GL_2(\mathbb{A}_{f})$.

Comment: You say $Z(\mathbb R)$ is the centre of $G(\mathbb R)$, but not what $G$ is.  Is it $\operatorname{GL}_2$?  If so, then I think your bijection (I guess that's what $\simeq$ means) is just using $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)Z(\mathbb R)\Gamma' = \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb R)$ and $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R) \cap Z(\mathbb R)\Gamma' = \Gamma$.

Comment: @Lspice, thank you very much! Do you know the decomposition of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})Z(\mathbb{R})=\Gamma’=GL_2((\mathbb{R})$? I don’t know how to decompose it! On the other hand, for the second question, I think I omitted some important condition, that is $GL_2(\mathbb{A})=GL_2(\mathbb{Q})GL_2(\mathbb{A}_f)$. I guess it should play a role at some place!

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator\S{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\G{GL}\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$I'm not sure what "the decomposition of $\S_2(\R)Z(\R)=\Gamma'=\G_2(\R)$" means; neither of those equalities holds.  Did you mean why $\S_2(\R)Z(\R)\Gamma'$ equals $\G_2(\mathbb R)$?  Given $g \in \G_2(\mathbb R)$, we have that $g\left(\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{\lvert d\rvert} \\ & \sqrt{\lvert d\rvert} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \operatorname{sgn}(d) \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right)^{-1}$ lies in $\S_2(\mathbb R)$, where $d = \det(g)$.

Comment: @LSpice, Oh, I am sorry for the typo. Your corrected equation and the answer is right! I confused $\Gamma’$ should be in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Thank you very much for such kind answer. In the mean while, have you ever thought the second question? It is one the key point when we pass from automorphic forms on real group to automorphic forms on adele group.

Comment: I am sceptical of your second question in the generality in which it is written (though I don't know that it is false).

Comment: @LSpice, thank you for your comment! It was written in some literature and so I asked this. When I know this, I will reply again. Thank u very much!